# git: Unable to track remote branch or do 'git pull'

Tags: git

Consider the following scenario:

`$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: /var/origin.git
  Push  URL: /var/origin.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master  tracked
    test    new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master  pushes to master  (up to date)`

Now I'd like to pull that remote 'test' branch. So I try this:

`$ git checkout --track origin/test
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/test' which can not be resolved as commit?`

Other people say to resolve this I simply need to do 'git pull'. This isn't the normal way I pull though. I usually do 'git pull origin master'. Here's what happens if I try:

`$ git pull
fatal: Where do you want to fetch from today?`

Something is fatally wrong here. I simply want to track/get the remote branch so I can make edits and push them back. What do I need to do to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

`git pull -u origin master` After doing this command I still could not do `git pull`.

`git push -u origin master` After doing this command I could now do `git pull` and also checkout the branch like I wanted to.

Comment: This implies your git version is older than 1.8.4.  `git push` updates all the `remotes/origin/` remote-branches, while `git fetch origin master` does not.  In newer versions of git, `git fetch` always updates everything, including when it's run from `git pull`.  In older versions of git you must run `git fetch` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run `git fetch origin` first.

`git remote show` connects to the remote in question and queries it, a la `git ls-remote` (you should try that too just to see it in operation—as with `git remote show` it only looks around, and does not touch anything):

```
$ env GIT_TRACE=1 git remote show origin
trace: built-in: git 'remote' 'show' 'origin'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'host' 'git-upload-pack '\''path'\'''
* remote origin
...
```

When `git remote show` prints "remote branches" at this point, it's telling you which branches exist (as local branches "over there") on the remote in question.  Along with that information, it also tells you whether *your* repository (the one "over here", not on the other host) has a copy of the remote's idea of those branches.  The above shows that your git *does* know about their git's `master`, i.e., you have an `origin/master`;<sup>1</sup> but your git *does not* know (yet) about their git's `test`, i.e., you *do not* have an `origin/test`.

In theory, your git *could* update its idea of what their git has "over there" right now: it's just found out, after all.  It could do this when you run `git ls-remote` as well.  But it does not: it's `git fetch` that instructs your git to pick up new information from their git and save it on your side.  The `show` and `ls-remote` operations merely let you know what `git fetch` *can* do; they don't actually do it.

The parenthetical remark, `(next fetch will store in remotes/origin)`, is telling you that if you run `git fetch`, your git will synchronize with their git, and—assuming nothing changes between the time you ran `git remote show` and the time you actually do run `git fetch`—acquire `remotes/origin/test`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The full name of this reference is `refs/remotes/origin/master`, but it can be abbreviated as either `origin/master` or `remotes/origin/master`.  Git is not terribly consistent about which abbreviations it uses, except that if a name becomes ambiguous, it tends to use a longer, more-explicit version.  See also [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).